# Проблемы с Data Binding

Tags: java, android, android-data-binding

Работаю с приложением с помощью  retrofit,  и в данном случае, использую Data Binding

При указании активности, this подсвечивается красным, и указавыет что  required type - Activity provided - MainActivity. Что могло пойти не так?

```
private ActivityMainBinding binding;
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
            binding.setPresenter(presenter);
    
        }
```

Comment: ну так и пиши вместо this MainActivity

Comment: Может быть вы забыли указать, что ваш класс расширяет класс активити?